# Systems of Linear Equations: Antifreeze Drain and Replace Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

> The radiator in your car contains 4 gallons of antifreeze and water. the mixture is 45% antifreeze. How much of the mixture should be drained and replaced with pure antifreeze in order to have a 60% antifreeze solution? Setup as a system of linear equations using two variables, and round to the nearest tenth of a gallon.

I'm having trouble setting this up as a system of linear equations in two variables.

So far I have the following:

Let $x =$ amount of pure antifreeze added

Let $y =$ amount of mixture/solution drained

Since 45% of the 4 gallons is already antifreeze, then 1.8 gallons out of the 4 is antifreeze.

We're trying to get a solution that is 60% antifreeze, so we should end up with 2.4 out of the 4 gallons being antifreeze in the radiator.

There's already 1.8 gallons of antifreeze in the car, and we'll be adding $x$ amount of pure antifreeze to that to get to 2.4 gallons: $1.8 + x = 2.4$

But before anything can be added some of the solution already in the radiator must be drained. Whatever amount is drained 45% of it will be antifreeze, so my first equation is this: $1.8 + x -0.45y = 2.4$

Simplify: $x -0.45y = 0.6$

I don't know how to set up the second equation.

Comment: Is $x=y$ the second equation I'm using then?

Comment: I think I'm losing my mind.  I was right yesterday, and misread your question today.  Yes, $x=y$ is the second equation.  We want to keep the radiator full, so we add ass much liquid as we drain.

Comment: Ah ok. Is my first equation $1.8 + x -0.45y = 2.4$ correct then?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: @saulspatz Solved, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

x = amount drained from radiator.
0.45(4 - x) + x = 0.6×4.

Comment: But I need to set it up as a system of equations with two variables.

Comment: Why such uselessness?  The need for x = y is trival.

Comment: Because that's what the textbook requires me to do.